# node js how to call webapi( x-www-form-urlencoded ) by sending data

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send data to a webservice ,
I put picture of how it goes from postman app.

I need to do it with node js, I could not found how to call webapi x-www-form-urlencoded.

Anyone help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the npm package [queryString](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) and did something like this:

```
var formdata=queryString.stringify({
SOMEDATA: SOMEVALUE,
MOREDATA: MOREVALUE
});

var options={
hostname: <hostname>,
path: <path>
method: 'POST',
headers:{
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length': formdata.length
}
}

let request = https.request(options,function(response){
//do something with the response data here
}
request.write(formdata);
request.end();
```

Comment: I want to know in your back-end are you not using library like **epress**, **hapi** etc.?

Comment: my backend is running express yes. why? is there a better way?